# Opening a port to a private network

Tags: vagrant, firewall

I ran into an interesting scenario, I am running a java web service in my Mac (EL Capitan). It listens on

```
http://localhost:7000/foo/bar
```

and

```
https://localhost:7443/foo/bar
```

I am running a vagrant box setup with a private network (`192.168.33.10`) and I am trying to access the web service running in the host from the guest with the following URLs.

1) `http://192.168.33.1:7000/foo/bar` and

2) `https://192.168.33.1:7443/foo/bar`

Strangely, I can access the link 2) from the guest, But when I try the link 1) I get a "Connection Refused" Message in the terminal.

When I did a `lsof -i:7000` & `lsof -i:7443` I get the following response. One says localhost:afs3-fileserver and the other says *:oracleas-https.

[image]

Is there relationship between the type of the services running & firewall blocking the service running in port 7000?

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Seems more superuser material than stackoverflow material. Its not a programming related question.

Comment: should I delete it and post it there or can someone migrate it?

Comment: I'd give it a moment to see if someone else has an opinion, I'm not exactly sure which stack site would be the best fit. The last thing we'd want is you being kicked somewhere else and then get your question closed as off-topic :)

Comment: Yes.  This is a superuser question.  But the answer is that localhost and private network are different networks.

Comment: What does `http://192.168.33.1:7000/foo/bar` yield from the *host* machine?

Comment: It gives back a json response

Comment: @Siguza any help would me much helpful.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is, I just wanted to check whether port- & IP-binding worked.